# creating an inventory management system app

Tags: mysql

for creating a inventory management app , i designed this database i want to store the product bought in the inventory as a positive value and the product sold as a negative value o nthe inventory so i can know the quantity remaining here is the database design 
[image]

its first time creating a database , does it answer my need ?

Comment: Can't judge a schema without first seeing what the `SELECT` will be.

Answer (score 2):

> and the product sold as a negative value

I personally wouldn't do this - it does not reflect reality. You can't have -25 widgets. You can have 10 in an inventory table and 15 in an orders (active) and/or sold (completed orders) table. You can have negative numbers - your bank account can have -25€ - this makes sense.

Take a look at http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/ for example inventory designs. -  [Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%C3%A9race)

---

Your scheme has joining rings, it is excessive, and data may be inconsistent. It is possible to have a joined record pair with `purshases.purshaseid = inventory.purshaseid and purshases.productid <> inventory.productid`.

I think `purshases.productid` is excess and must be removed. Its value must be selected from joined record in `inventory` table. And the same with `inventory`-`product`-`orders` ring. - [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)